# Accepted answer not showing as accepted in profile page

Tags: support, profile-page, accepted-answer

I am facing a strange situation here. I have given an answer to a question and it is the accepted answer when viewing the question, but when I open my profile page the answer is not shown as the accepted answer. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1405921/mairaj-ahmad) is link to my profile and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30431959/call-js-function-from-code-behind-c-sharp/30432212#30432212) is the question.
The title of the question is

> Call JS function from code behind C#

Screenshot of my profile:

> [image]

Comment: I see it as accepted in your profile (summary view or details view).

Comment: I see it correct here: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1405921/mairaj-ahmad?tab=reputation

Comment: In summary view.

Comment: Please see the image  this is what i am seeing.

Comment: I see that too, just saying that you did get the points for it.

Comment: Yes i got points for this.

Answer (score 2):

In the **Reputation** section of your profile, reps gained from upvotes do not have the background color (which depicts an accepted answer). However, in the **Answers** section, you can see it as accepted (having green background). Screenshot of your profile:

[image]

Comment: Well i am not sure but this looks to be the point.

Answer (score 2):

The profile page shows you the four most recent votes or accepts that you received. If you click on [view more](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1405921/mairaj-ahmad?tab=reputation&sort=time) you'll see them all.

Your Call JS function answer was both accepted and upvoted. The upvote is shown (as +10) but there's no room on the four item list for the accept. If you look at the [complete list](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1405921/mairaj-ahmad?tab=reputation&sort=time) both the upvote and the accept are shown.

Upvotes are always shown with a white background whether the answer has been accepted or not.