# Non-accepted answers highlighted as green in Summary tab

Tags: discussion, bug, profile-page, accepted-answer, activity

On my Stack Overflow profile's [Activity/Summary tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8708364/u12-f%cc%89%cd%8b%cc%85%cc%be%cc%87orward?tab=summary):

You can see that my answer to the question "How to clear a variable" clearly wasn't accepted, but why does it show a green background?

Screenshot:

[image]

Why is the background green? It isn't accepted, I think this is a bug

Comment: It doesn't show that your answer is the accepted one but the question has an accepted answer

Comment: @Minot Ok, but it still seems misleading

Comment: Still, not a bug. As a bug, this would just get a [tag:status-bydesign] and that's it. I'd change this into a feature request asking to use the green background for answers only if the answer is accepted, then there's a (very slim) chance it will be done.

Comment: Isnt this also noted as an answer to the question on the redesign of the activity page?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New responsive Activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page)

Comment: This was [already reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372749)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Identify answers which might yet get accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139186/282094),   https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/257197/282094 choosing to search for two of the most relevant tags finds likely candidates for duplicates:   https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86064/282094  even if they don't at first seem the same you can see the underlying reasons are.

Comment: @glorfindel, since you reviewed to leave this open did you want to add [tag:status-planned] (like the [duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372749/282094) has) or reverse your decision?